# "My grammy never give gifts"

Tags: meaning

What does "My grammy never give gifts" mean?
Basically, I want to know the meaning of *grammy*.

Comment: "Grammy" is a diminutive for "grandmother" (it's how a child might refer to his grandmother). Note that your sentence, in its current form, isn't quite right: it should be "Grammy never giveS gifts" or "Grammy never gavE gifts" (past tense).

Comment: @DanBron In this case it would be "gave", since it's a [quote](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075686/quotes?item=qt0373252).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the correct sentence is "My grammy never gives gifts".

The word grammy in this context is a colloquial term for grandmother and is very localised. It is not used by the majority of English speakers.